# Subtract each row of specific column from dataframe and add to the list -python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to subtract each ow of column A from DataFrame aa and add those to the list.

`a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,(5,4)),columns=['A','B','C','D'])`
 `list=[]`

I am so sorry for this such a basic question but I can't find the solution.

Comment: a['A'].to_list()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Just realized you only wanted to extract a column from a `DataFrame` as a list. In that case, like @arkhadiusz commented, you can just use:

```
a.A.to_list()
```

Note that this won't remove the column from your `DataFrame`. If you'd like to completely remove it from your `DataFrame`, you can use:

```
a.pop('A').to_list()
```

---

Assuming you want to subtract a constant value from each element in a column of your `DataFrame`, you can try something like this:

```
x = 0.5 # some constant value you want to subtract
[val1 - val2 for val1, val2 in zip(a.A.to_list(), [x] * a.shape[0])]
```

Or if you want to subtract different values for each element, you can try:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[val1 - val2 for val1, val2 in zip(a.A.to_list(), x)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this!! I'm sorry for the lack of explanation, but I want to do is to subtract the number in the row from the number in the row above it!

Comment: Oh wait, actually I got this by myself. I turned column to the list then used for loop to subtract each values and appended to another list.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want this:

To get a numpy array:

```
lst = a[["B","C","D"]].subtract(a["A"], axis=0).values
```

To get a 2d list:

```
lst = a[["B","C","D"]].subtract(a["A"], axis=0).values.T.tolist()
```